# Implode array value to string by key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have an array like

[image: Array Picture]

how to implode array by key.

```
1001 => ['1,5,6...']
1002 => ['2,3,4...']
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Collection of [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) so you can use the [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) method to do this. You want to turn each Collection into a new Collection of the `kode_barang`s from each Collection.

```
$ids = $groups->map(function ($collection, $key) {
    return $collection->implode('kode_barang', ',');
});
```

Then `$ids` is a new Collection which you can use `toArray` on to get an array of IDs (if you need an array instead of a collection):

```
$ids->toArray();
```

Comment: if i use the code, result array like 

1001 => Collection {#390 ▼
      #items: array:10 [▼
        0 => 1
        1 => 5
        2 => 6
        3 => 7
        4 => 8
        5 => 9
        6 => 10
        7 => 11
        8 => 12
        9 => 13
      ]
    }
    1002 => Collection {#567 ▼
      #items: array:8 [▼
        0 => 2
        1 => 20
        2 => 21
        3 => 22
        4 => 23
        5 => 12
        6 => 12
        7 => 13
      ]
    }

but i want kode_barang implode..

Comment: @Dunhill I've updated the answer to implode the IDs for you, you just need to replace `pluck` with `implode`.